# Casting int as a double is returning #INF00

Tags: c, casting

So I am trying to cast (3/17) as double. This is for an assignment so the professor wants it to be this way for some reason.

I am trying to cast it by doing the following:

```
(double)(3/17)
```

Actual code:

```
int assignment7()
{
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14
    int a=0;
    double Ny=0,y=0,z=0,x=0,amod2=0;
    printf("Enter values for x,y,z and a(must be an odd number): ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%d",&x,&y,&z,&a);
    amod2=a%2;
    printf("%.2lf\n",test);
    Ny=y / (double)(3/17) - z + x / amod2 + PI;
    printf("%lf\n",Ny);
```

}

The problem is occurring on the second to last line where it is interpreting 3/17 as an int thus it would equal 0. y / 0

Professors exact instructions: 
"General equation: y = y / (3/17) - z + x / (a % 2) + PI (recall: a is an integer; the 3 and 17 constants in the equation should be left as integers initially, but explicitly type-casted as floating-point values)"

Comment: Are you really making the `#include` inside your function?

Answer (score 3):

`(3/17)` is equal to 0 because it is evaluated using integer arithmetic, and so you get a divide by zero, which is of course a run-time error. Change:

```
(double)(3/17)
```

to:

```
(3.0 / 17.0)
```

Note that the cast is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You have a division by zero as `3/17` is zero.

Instead use doubles to begin with: `3.0 / 17.0`, then you don't even need the cast.